# database index cannot rebuild

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I cannot rebuild the index in my table. When I try to rebuild, I get the error "lock request timeout exceeded". Now when I try to kill the blocking process which has an ID of 22 (system process), it says only user processes can be killed.

How do I access the database and rebuild the index without the system blocking it?

UPDATE:

Fixed it by running an `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` statement to rebuild the primary key index offline and it worked and allowed the lock for rebuilding the index.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the sys process causing your problem? If so, you will have to stop the MSSQL service, that will kill all the system processes. Then start it up again.

Comment: yes. when i stop the service and restart it, the database goes into recovery then after it finishes recovering, i'd run sp_who2 to check the blocking process and there's only the id 22 which is a system process (afaik all ids 50 and below are system processes) which causes the "user processes can be killed." error message to appear again when i try to kill the process.

Comment: hmmm, are you sure, it's blocking? can you show us the sp_who2 output

Comment: i can't anymore sorry. i wasn't able to follow up on this. i fixed it by running a Index Rebuild in offline mode for the table and it worked. the blkby column in sp2 shows only the id 22 which ,i'm not sure, but probably from the web services accessing the database.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Fixed it by running an ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD statement to rebuild the primary key index offline and it worked and allowed the lock for rebuilding the index.